# Looping at specified indexes

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 2 large lists, each with about 100 000 elements each and one being larger than the other, that I want to iterate through. My loop looks like this:

```
for i in list1:
   for j in list2:
       function()
```

This current looping takes too long. However, `list1` is a list that needs to be checked from `list2` but, from a certain index, there are no more instances beyond in `list2`. This means that looping from indexes might be faster but the problem is I do not know how to do so.

In my project, list2 is a list of dicts that have three keys: `value`, `name`, and `timestamp`. list1 is a list of the `timestamp`s in order. The function is one that takes the `value` based off the `timestamp` and puts it into a csv file in the appropriate `name` column.

This is an example of entries from list1:

```
[1364310855.004000, 1364310855.005000, 1364310855.008000]
```

This is what list2 looks like:

```
{"name":"vehicle_speed","value":2,"timestamp":1364310855.004000}
{"name":"accelerator_pedal_position","value":4,"timestamp":1364310855.004000}
{"name":"engine_speed","value":5,"timestamp":1364310855.005000}
{"name":"torque_at_transmission","value":-3,"timestamp":1364310855.008000}
{"name":"vehicle_speed","value":1,"timestamp":1364310855.008000}
```

In my final csv file, I should have something like this:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03563948671103920273

Comment: i think it might be worth to explain what are you going to do in your "function()" - maybe  you don't have to do a nested loop... What is your end goal? What do you want to do with those two lists?

Comment: Describe precisely how the values in list1 determine the range of values in list2 to which to apply the function.

Comment: Are you talking about slicing from list2 `list2[0:2]`

Comment: Now, when you added a last paragraph, it makes more sense. Please provide a sample input data for list1 and list2 and expected output data.4-5 rows for each list should be enough.

Comment: I assume that you are looking for a way to speed up the loop. I am not explaining how to deal with the csv output. Is that ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to be fast, you should restructure the data that you have in list2 in order to speedup your lookups:

```
# The following code converts list2 into a multivalue dictionary

from collections import defaultdict

list2_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in list2:
    list2_dict[item['timestamp']].append((item['name'], item['value']))
```

This gives you a much faster way to look up your timestamps:

```
print(list2_dict)

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    1364310855.008: [('torque_at_transmission', -3), ('vehicle_speed', 0)], 
    1364310855.005: [('engine_speed', 0)], 
    1364310855.004: [('vehicle_speed', 0), ('accelerator_pedal_position', 0)]})
```

Lookups will be much more efficient when using `list2_dict`:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2_dict[i]:
        # here j is a tuple in the form (name, value)
        function()
```

Comment: Great answer. It solves this problem but now another problem has arisen as the order has become lost. Is there no way to sort the defaultdict by keys?

Comment: You can use a sorted dictionary: OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

Comment: I see. Just to know but how can I access the value by itself? Calling by index gives me the value and the key but calling by key gives me an error

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, are you talking about the ordered dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to only want to use the elements in list2 that correspond to `i*2` and `i*2+1`, That is elements 0, 1 and 2, 3, ...

You only need one loop.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    j = list[i*2]
    k = list2[j+1]
    # Process function using j and k
```

You will only process to the end of list one.

Answer (score 0):

i think [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) module is a perfect match for your goals...

```
import ujson            # 'ujson' (Ultra fast JSON) is faster than the standard 'json'
import pandas as pd

filter_list = [1364310855.004000, 1364310855.005000, 1364310855.008000]

def file2list(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        return [ujson.loads(line) for line in f]

# Use pd.read_json('data.json') instead of pd.DataFrame(load_data('data.json'))
# if you have a proper JSON file
#
# df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df = pd.DataFrame(file2list('data.json'))

# filter DataFrame with 'filter_list'
df = df[df['timestamp'].isin(filter_list)]

# convert UNIX timestamps to readable format
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')

# pivot data frame
# fill NaN's with zeroes
df = df.pivot(index='timestamp', columns='name', values='value').fillna(0)

# save data frame to CSV file
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',')

#pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
#print(df)
```

output.csv

```
timestamp,accelerator_pedal_position,engine_speed,torque_at_transmission,vehicle_speed
2013-03-26 15:14:15.004,4.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
2013-03-26 15:14:15.005,0.0,5.0,0.0,0.0
2013-03-26 15:14:15.008,0.0,0.0,-3.0,1.0
```

PS i don't know where did you get [Latitude,Longitude] columns from, but it's pretty easy to add those columns to your result DataFrame - just add the following lines before calling `df.to_csv()`

```
df.insert(0, 'latitude', 0)
df.insert(1, 'longitude', 0)
```

which would result in:

```
timestamp,latitude,longitude,accelerator_pedal_position,engine_speed,torque_at_transmission,vehicle_speed
2013-03-26 15:14:15.004,0,0,4.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
2013-03-26 15:14:15.005,0,0,0.0,5.0,0.0,0.0
2013-03-26 15:14:15.008,0,0,0.0,0.0,-3.0,1.0
```